# Factory instead of switch

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method:

```
Label LabelFactory(string template, object id) {
  Label label = GetLabelTemplate(template);
  if (label == null) throw new Exception("Unknown Label type or Label cannot be loaded.");
  switch (template) {
      case "BTAC":
          label.Data = GetDataForLabel<BTAC>(id); break;
      case "KTAC":
          label.Data = GetDataForLabel<KTAC>(id); break;
      ...
  }
  return label;
}
```

The calling site doesn't know about types *(BTAC, KTAC, etc.)*, so I had to use this *template* parameter. However, I don't like this switch. Is there any elegant way to substitute it?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Well what exactly don't you like about it? There are various options here, such as a `Dictionary<string, Func<object, string>>` but it's hard to know what to recommend without knowing what the requirements are.

Comment: You might want to cross post this over at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `switch` is just one of ways to implement factory. If you need expandability, try to implement Register-Resolve-Release pattern. F.e. you can use one of IOC-manager with named registering/resolving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Elegance* is in the eye of the beholder; which happens to be anyone reading the code after you.
That said; There is no elegant way, no.

You have to fall back to [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and find out which class corresponds to the string variable template sent in.
Maybe [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) helps.

HTH